# Looking for a book series about a brother and sister with magic powers, golden hook

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, magic

There was a book series about a brother and sister. They had magic powers. Their parents ended up being like Gods there were a ton of gods in this series from all mythologies.

They had famous weapons in the book series. The brother and sister started off in a bookshop and then a stranger came into their bookstore and then that's how the story starts.

The brother ends up turning into a man with a golden hook on his hand that was forged from all the famous swords they collected and the sister was more magically talented but the brother had the famous swords.

Comment: Do you remember when it was written, what language it was in, anything about the cover? You can [edit] to add anything else that might be helpful. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as and when.

Answer (score 8):

This is the *The Secrets of the Immortal Nicolas Flamel* series, by Michael Scott.

Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Alchemyst:_The_Secrets_of_the_Immortal_Nicholas_Flamel):

> Sophie and Josh Newman are 15-year-old twins who are working at their summer jobs in The Coffee Cup in San Francisco (Sophie works at The Coffee Cup, Josh works at the bookstore on the other side of the street) when a mysterious man, John Dee, comes into the bookstore for a book, the Codex – or Book of Abraham the Mage. Josh witnesses both Nick and Perry using magic. He discovers that Nick is not an ordinary bookseller, but is the medieval and the legendary alchemist, Nicholas Flamel, being kept alive by making the elixir of life (a secret from the Codex) for him and his wife, Perenelle. Dee also uses magic and takes the Codex by force while Josh is holding it – resulting in two pages being left behind; "The Final Summoning" pages that Dee needs to raise the Dark Elders, the beings whom Dee serves, and who have kept him immortal for several hundred years. Both Flamels need the Codex to make the elixir of life, or they will age rapidly and die within a month. Also, if they do not retrieve the Codex, Dee will summon the Dark Elders to destroy the world and return to an age in which humans are but slaves and food.

The swords show up in later books in the series. From the [Wikipedia page from the third book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sorceress:_The_Secrets_of_the_Immortal_Nicholas_Flamel), *The Sorceress*:

> Gilgamesh is wounded by the Archon, but the twins use their newfound magical powers to protect the King. While making their escape, Josh loses Clarent, and Dee grabs the sword, reuniting it with its twin, Excalibur. The two swords fuse together to make a new sword. Flamel, Palamedes and the twins flee for Stonehenge with the Wild Hunt, Dee, and the police after them.

At the end of the last book,

> Josh sits on the center of the Pyramid of the Sun and begins to read the Codex, discovering that Sophie, Joan, Scathach, Dare, and Aten lead the survivors onto the new Earth and assist them for several hundred years before returning to the present time. He then combines the Four Swords of Power (Clarent, Excalibur, Durendal, and Joyeuse) to create the fifth power--- Aether. The swords form a hook, revealing that Josh becomes/is Marethyu (hence revealing the reason why characters have always thought Marethyu seemed familiar). He plunges his hook into the center of the Pyramid of the Sun, speaking aloud the last words he read in the Codex ("Today I become Death, the destroyer of worlds") and thereby destroying Danu Talis. On Alcatraz, Nicholas and Perenelle spend their last moments together, content. Marethyu appears and tells Perenelle and the Alchemyst that he is Josh and takes them to Paris, apparently for the Flamels to die. In a letter to Sophie, Josh (Marethyu) describes Aoife and Niten's wedding, where Scathach was the bridesmaid and promises to Sophie that he will always watch over her.
>  <sub>([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Enchantress:_The_Secrets_of_the_Immortal_Nicholas_Flamel)</sub>

---

Identified by recognizing the plot.

Comment: I knew this just from the title :-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - That wasn't the title when I answered it ;)